# VBA Code showing error with older files "xslx" issue?

Tags: excel, vba

I still seemed to be having issue with a code I am using to transfer multiple workbooks into 1 workbook.  This code has worked to transfer 500 files into respective workbooks.
I have followed the exact same process for older files, but this is still throwing the same issue it was before. When I started this project, I tried to do it with the older workbooks in the file, and this happened but it worked perfectly with newer ones. Here is the code I am using for the older files, which is exactly the same except the file path is different to reference the files to be transferred. All of the files in the folder are `.xslx' I have checked this by selecting that the file extension be shown. I am totally beside myself as to why this is not working. When I run this code now it transfers the first 8 workbooks then gives me an error? Any ideas please?

Working VBA:

```
 Sub TransferToMaster()
Dim Path            As String
Dim FileName        As String
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim WS              As Worksheet
 
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Path = "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Invoices Jones UK Group\Paid\JJ0500-JJ0599" 'Change as needed
FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
Do Until FileName = ""
    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
    For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
        WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Next WS
    Wkb.Close False
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

The only thing I am changing in this code is "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Invoices Jones UK Group\Paid\JJ0300-JJ0399"
I have tried several variations of this line FileName = Dir(Path & ""*.xlsx", vbNormal), from ""*.xls*", and ""*.xl*". I have also done lots of research on this forum to try to resolve the problem if it is the file extensions. But I don't get why it loads up the 8 sheets and stops. When its been working perfectly? I will upload a screenshot of my code.

Comment: The only thing I am changing in this code is "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Invoices Jones UK Group\Paid\JJ0300-JJ0399"

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Please, insert the next code line after `FileName = Dir(Path & "\...`: `Debug.Print "The file name is " & FileName: Stop`. What does it return in Immediate Window when code stops on this line? To see Immediate Window press `CTRL + G` being in VBE...

Comment: Just trying to upload a screen shot, but can't seem to work out how?

Comment: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: "The file name is Debug. Print "The file name is " & FileName: Stop.  - it doesn't like this and is going red says syntax error .  " & FileName: Stop  just highlights the stop work yellow. the error given on G8 after syntax error is The file name is JJ300 - Priory - Old Rectory Brede - FF shower room 2 - Invoice.xlsx
The file name is JJ300 - Priory - Old Rectory Brede - FF shower room 2 - Invoice.xlsx
The file name is JJ300 - Priory - Old Rectory Brede - FF shower room 2 - Invoice.xlsx
The file name is JJ300 - Priory - Old Rectory Brede - FF shower room 2 - Invoice.xlsx

Comment: No error was there.. The code stops on `Stop` command. So, the path is OK. On which row does your code raise an error. Just copy here the yellow row. Or a part of it...

Comment: On my original code, It isn't going yellow, and no message comes up on 'CTRL + G' it just loads the first 8 sheets up and then stops and gives me the application/object defined error. Its just mind boggling as this code has transferred 100 workbooks into 1 workbook 5 times over?

Comment: Comment out the `ws.Copy` line and check the code open and closes the files OK. Open the workbooks read only with `Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName,1,1`). If the code fails try opening the file it failed on manually.

Comment: @CDP1802 you my friend are a genius...there was nothing wrong with my code. It was errors in the files. It is working, when it gets to the last sheet transferred if I open the following one manually, it tells me there is an error in the file! So its a little annoying but still don't have to manually copy another 300 worksheets! Thank you so much. I should have had more faith in myself to know my code was correct.

Comment: @FaneDuru thank you so much for your input. I will just double check that this is resolved and then....